# bash "$@" not working with arguments starting with '-'

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, parameter-passing

I am working on an option driven bash script that will use getopts. The script has cases where it can accept multiple options and specific cases where only one option is accepted. While testing a few cases out I ran into this issue which I have reduced down to pseudo-code for this question.

```
for arg in "$@"; do
  echo ${arg}
done
echo "end"
```

Running below returns:

```
$ ./test.sh -a -b
-a

end
```

I am running bash 4.1.2, why isn't the -b returned on the empty line? I assume this has to do with the '-'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your exact error, but this is the risk of using `echo`: if `$arg` *is* a valid option, it will be treated as such, not a string to print. Use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s\n' "$arg"
```

Comment: But none of `-b` or `-a` are valid flags for `echo` right? The answer is fine, but wondering OP's output is incorrect

Comment: Correct; I have no idea why `-b` appear to be treated as an option by `echo`.

Comment: In any case, this would have been an issue with `-n` too, and the solution is the same

Comment: Thanks this answered it. Again, I converted my other code to pseudo-code for the question and generalized the args to -a -b alphabetically but my real options pertaining to my script are -c and -e. echo -e is a valid option, hence why it wasn't printed on my end.

Comment: @Jeremy In the future you'll always copy-paste your test case from your post and verify that it shows the problem you intend to show, right :P

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you have applied any "shift" commands that might remove the arguments before you test then (typical in a argument collection block that might include a case statement)